# Cannot build Android project with preview compile and target sdk version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to test how my Android app would work with SDK version UpsideDownCake which is now is a preview version. I apply this version to my `app` module as following:

```kotlin
android {
    compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"
    buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0-rc2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.8.5")
    // Other dependecies
}
```

and in other (library) modules:

```kotlin
android {
    compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"
    buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0-rc2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 23
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Library dependencies
}
```

When I start to sync Android Studio with gradle files I get warnings for some of dependencies I use. They look as following:

> Failed to resolve: com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.8.5. Affected Modules: app.

I can't build this project. What can I do about this error?

Comment: Does it still give warnings after reverting compile/target to sdk 33? Also can you post where you declare repositories for dependencies? This library version is available on MavenCentral, so it's surprising it doesn't resolve

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle (Module: app)`, you didn’t specify the OneSignal dependence properly
According to the documentation it should be this way

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
}
```

you should look through the docs for the [android-sdk-setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup)

Comment: I did specify this dependency sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: The only dependency that you need is the one that Enike Braimoh mentioned, NOT the one from your question.

Comment: What difference does it make? This is the last version of OneSignal library and we don't use version ranges for dependencies in our project

Comment: It’s in the documentation that you need to specify it that way to use the SDK, go through the documentation and follow the instructions. it would work perfectly.

Comment: If you checked Maven Central for this library, you would see that [OP's version is available there](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.onesignal/OneSignal/4.8.5), so the dependency declaration itself should not be the problem